# How does a log4net instance get found after instantiating?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, log4net

I am using log4net in a mvc4 application (for academic purposes). I am calling this method in *global.asax* in the `Application_Start()` method.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Then in any controller of my app i can call this method:

```
 ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T));
```

The question is since when i am calling the `Configure()` method in the `Application_Start()` method, but i am not storing a reference to it in any variable, how does the `GetLogger()` method know where to look, more precisely where does it find the log4net instance?

Personally, I can't imagine a path to it (except maybe if i knew its memory location where it got loaded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log4net stores a reference to it in a static variable. The `GetLogger` method has access to that variable and returns the appropriate value. (Actually, I'm oversimplifying this a bit. See the log4net source code for full details.)

This is a variation of [the singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

By the way, you can get log4net to create more than one logger instance (as I say, it's a variation on singleton). To do so, configure the additional logger(s) via the [logger element](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#loggers), then pass the name you've assigned via the element's `name` attribute to `LogManager.GetLogger()`. The `GetLogger` method will use the name passed to it as a lookup key for the appropriate static logger instance and create that instance when you first ask for it.

Comment: The singleton pattern cleared it up a bit. So the GetLogger method just returns the static Log4Net object. This means that you can acces any static object this away, as long as it has been created(using a static constructor). And even if it has not been created, it will be created when you first acces it, correct?

Comment: Correct. The logger is created when it is first accessed.